# change list direction based on the text

Tags: html, css

I have a list which is generated from user input. The content of the list can be from any language, including RTL languages.

**How do I change the list's direction automatically based on the language?**

I know `unicode-bidi` works just fine on any regular old text, and the `direction` property cant get the "auto" value like the Dir attribute.

eg:

```
<ul>
  <li>english</li>
  <li>left to right</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>עברית</li>
  <li>ימין לשמאל</li>
</ul>
```

with only css changes should output 2 lists one floating to the left and with the dots to the left of the text and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I haven't found any answer that uses only css to change dynamically (and checks autumaticly),

the second best option that works is to add `dir="auto"` to the `<ul>` or `<ol>` like this:

```
<ul dir="auto">
  <li></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I just asked the guy responsible for the generation of the lists to add this to his c code, while the `unicode-bidi: plaintext;` css rule stayed.

As of now, I believe there is no option to do the same with just css3

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `lang` attribute on elements in html. This combines with `unicode-bidi` should allow you to do what you want to do.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/veytqdwx/9

Answer (score 0):

Use a class on the parent div to identify.  If the language is something like English, assign the parent a class.  Since your content is dynamic, this should be possible.

```
<div class="english-menu">
   <ul> 
     ...
   </ul>
  ...</div>
```

And then style is accordingly in css

```
.english-menu{
   float: left;
   ... //whatever else
}
```

Comment: adding this would mean I need to find and edit someone else's c function in a sea of code, is there no other option?

Comment: also, this will require a function to check which language is used